# ZF2: add global variable to view

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm trying to learn ZF2 and I need to find out about some basics. 
What I want to do is define certain variables that are available in all templates. 
I have an IndexController extendes BaseController and in BaseController I tried this:

```
public function onDispatch( \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e ){
  $this->view->superImportantArray = array('data' => ...); 
}
```

Of course this is a ZF1 approach and doesn't work. So how do I do this? Would be thankful for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and avoid using custom base controllers if you can. You can achieve this using the events system. Put `use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;` at the top of your `Module.php`, and then add:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER, function($e) {
        $layoutViewModel = $e->getViewModel();
        $childViewModels = $layoutViewModel->getChildren();
        if (count($childViewModels) == 0) {
            // probably an AJAX request
            return;
        }
        $viewModel = $childViewModels[0];

        $viewModel->superImportantArray = array('date' => ...);
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. two questions: 1. why should I avoid using custom base constrollers? and 2. in my superImportantArray I want to store the user login data - but I seem to be unable to access $this->getServiceLocator in onBootstrap... what do I do?

Comment: Use `$e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('xxx')` within the event to access things from the service manager. Custom base controllers are inflexible and hard to test. There are some use cases for them, but most things can be done using events.

Comment: awesome, this works:$e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('AuthService')->getIdentity(); thank you very much!